# How to use samba with pycurl?

Tags: python, curl, smb, pycurl

I have the following code:

```
crl = pycurl.Curl()
crl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'user:pass')
crl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'url')
crl.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
crl.perform()
```

How can I use a similar code to work with SMB protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2005-11/0086.html), set CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH option to value CURLAUTH_NTLM. If this doesn't work try [pysmb](http://pythonhosted.org/pysmb).